# Что такое файловый хостинг, и чем он отличается от виртуального хостинга?

Tags: веб-программирование, хостинг, hosting

Требуется понять, что такое файловый хостинг. На википедии написано, что файловый хостинг - просто какое-то хранилище файлов для скачивания другими пользователями. На английской версии википедии файловый хостинг определяется как облачное хранилище данных, вроде Icloud, Google Drive и Onedrive. Yagpt вообще в ступор вводит своим ответом.
В принципе, что такое виртуальный хостинг, мне понятно. Но что всё-таки называют файловым хостингом, до меня не доходит.

смотрел ролики на ютубе, сравнивал определения на википедии, спросил у yagpt.

Comment: чем красная машина отличается от грузовой? это примерно суть вашего вопроса.

Comment: *"На википедии написано, что файловый хостинг - просто какое-то хранилище файлов для скачивания другими пользователями"* --- что вас смутило в этом определении?

Comment: "Файловый" - это назначение хостинга, буквально означает, что хостинг предназначен для хранения файлов (а не хостинга веб-сайтов, например). "Виртуальный" - способ реализации, выделение виртуальной машины под хостинг. Это вообще не взаимоисключающие понятия.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем уверен в корректности терминов, но возможно в вашем случае сравнивается следующее:

Файловый хостинг - условно, жесткий диск с файлами(СХД), доступ к которому осуществляется по сети.

Виртуальный хостинг - полноценный сервер с ОС, на котором может выполняться код.

Answer (score 0):

Файловый хостинг (часто его называют бекап-хостинг во избежания путаницы с файлообменниками) - это только выделенное место на диске сервера. К нему есть доступы только по (s)ftp и, иногда, по другим протоколам **для обмена файлами**.
На нем не установлено ПО веб-сервера (apaсhe, php и тд) и, соответственное, к нему нет доступа по http, нет домена и пр.

Иногда файловыми хостингами называют сервисы для обмена файлами (файлообменники). Что по моему мнению не верно. У них пользователь может закачать файл, а другие его скачать по http.

Comment: *"Что не верно."* Источник бы. Английская википедия не делает такого различия.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat 1. не знаю насколько ты прав (вполне возможно что нет), но пеливикия написана юзерами и там полно косяков. 2. Что там на английком нам в данном случае не важно. У нас русскоязычные хостреры предоставляют файловый хостинг. И файлообменник и файловый хостинг - суть вещи разные.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я тут погуглил и.. фшоке. Действительно  сейчас файловыми хостингами стали называть файлообменники и и нас (долбанные тупые копирастеры нагадили). О. ужас.. Я отредактировать ответ, но мнение осталось тоже - это неправильное название. Файлообменники к  хостинг-услугам отношения не имеют (тем более в РФ после последних законов).